# Hyperlink to download excel using jxls

Tags: excel, export, jxls

**First the context:**

I am using jxls to export to an excel using an excel template & its working fine.I am saving to a folder under webcontent

```
WebContent\reports\report_output.xls
```

**What additionally i need to do:**

I have to provide a hyperlink to the user in the webpage that will access this saved file.

**What i am failing to do:**

The hyperlink is throwing exception (resource not found) if i don't refresh my web-content in eclipse

**My questions**

a. Refreshing a webcontent through java & isit nessarily the way out to this situation?
b. Alternative approach keeping in mind i cant do the following

1.cant use a spring mvc framework(time & effort constraints) and stick with jxls only.

2.can't save the file in local drive and access through hyperlink for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using using a particular URK pattern the servlet will respond back after copying the content and streaming back with mime type as XSL. here is the working example:
["Exporting To Excel: JXLS"](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/07/this-method-is-getting-called-from-ajax.html).